# How can i create sql-like AS3 ArrayCollection grouping

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, group-by, arraycollection, flash-builder4.5

I have an `arrayCollection` which I created dynamically like one at bottom:

```
arrCol = ({"ID":ids[i][0], "Price":ids[i][1], "OtherInfo":ids[i][2]});
```

I want to group data and summarise `Price` by ID.

If this `ArrayCollection` was a SQL table, I could use a query like this:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Price), OtherInfo 
FROM TableA 
GROUP BY ID
```

So how can I set an AS3 function like the query example in SQL or is there any native `ArrayCollection` class for this?

Comment: The AarrayCollection class has no such functions. You'll have to iterate over the array and save the sum in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, there is no built in function available for your need(sum,groupby) so we need to do manually below code will help you.

```
var arrCol:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

arrCol.addItem({"ID":1, "Price":100, "OtherInfo":"info"});
arrCol.addItem({"ID":1, "Price":700, "OtherInfo":"info"});
arrCol.addItem({"ID":2, "Price":100, "OtherInfo":"info"});
arrCol.addItem({"ID":2, "Price":200, "OtherInfo":"info"});
arrCol.addItem({"ID":3, "Price":100, "OtherInfo":"info"});
arrCol.addItem({"ID":3, "Price":400, "OtherInfo":"info"});
arrCol.addItem({"ID":3, "Price":100, "OtherInfo":"info"});

var dic:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

for each (var item:Object in arrCol) 
{
    if(!dic[item.ID]){
        dic[item.ID] = item;
    }
    else{                        
        var oldSumObj:Object = dic[item.ID];
        oldSumObj.Price +=item.Price;
        dic[item.ID] = oldSumObj;
    }
}

var groupedList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

for each (var itemObj:Object in dic) 
{
    groupedList.addItem(itemObj);
}
```

output will be:

```
"groupedList"   mx.collections.ArrayCollection (@27af939)   
    [0] Object (@8836569)   
        ID  1   
        OtherInfo   "info"  
        Price   800 [0x320] 
    [1] Object (@87a7c71)   
        ID  2   
        OtherInfo   "info"  
        Price   300 [0x12c] 
    [2] Object (@87a7bc9)   
        ID  3   
        OtherInfo   "info"  
        Price   600 [0x258]
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can't make SQL type queries in AS3, you can use its bevy of methods to achieve the same result.

```
// Work with an array.  Child elements must be an associative array (structure/object/hash-table)
var ac:Array = [
    {"name":"apple", "price":100, "color":"red"},
    {"name":"banana", "price":50, "color":"yellow"},
    {"name":"pear", "price":250, "color":"green"},
]

// Apply the order your want based on the property you're concerned with.
ac.sortOn("price", Array.ASCENDING)

// If necessary, create a subset of that array with the "select"-ed columns.
var output:Array = [];
for each (var entry:Object in ac) {
    output.push({entry.name, entry.color});
}

// Printing output will result in
// 0:{"name":"banana", "color":"yellow"},
// 1:{"name":"apple", "color":"red"},
// 2:{"name":"pear", "color":"green"}
```